# Ember 2.12 to Ember 2.13 -- Issue around rename of router to _routerMicrolib

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I am an Ember newbie.
Working on migration of project from Ember 2.11 to 2.15.

After migrating from 2.12 to 2.13, I am running into this issue related to a deprecation of router renamed to _routerMicrolib (https://emberjs.com/deprecations/v2.x/#toc_ember-router-router-renamed-to-ember-router-_routermicrolib), when I ran the route unit tests.

1. Issue calling a router refresh

this.get('router').refresh(), gives:

> undefined is not a constructor (evaluating
>   'route.get('router').refresh()')

this.router.refresh:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'this.router._routerMicrolib.refresh')

2. Issue calling route.get('router').transitionTo

route.transitionTo:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'this.router._routerMicrolib.get')

route.get('router').transitionTo:

> undefined is not a constructor (evaluating
>   'route.get('router').refresh()')

3. Issue calling this.router.send('somemessage')

> undefined is not an object (evaluating '(_routerMicrolib4 =
>   this._routerMicrolib).trigger')

Anyone has an idea how to call refresh, and get in these scenarios?

---

Update:

The above lines are called under actions example as:

> export default Base.extend({
>   init(){ ...} 
>   actions: {
>           refreshRoute(){
>               this.refresh();
>               //this.get('router').refresh();
>           }
>       } });

Comment: Where are you doing `this.get('router)`?

Comment: updated above, called under actions

Comment: What is that `Base`, is it extending `Ember.Route` ?

Comment: Yes as: export default Ember.Route.extend

Comment: What happened when you tried this.get('_routerMicrolib').refresh(); instead of this.get('router').refresh() ?